# Passing a class that use a method as a member

Tags: c#

I've been learning C# for the past 6 months or so and am currently stuck on a turn-based battle system for a game.

I have tried a couple of different things and watched loads of videos about it but I didn't find what I was looking for. Maybe it's impossible but here it is. Also, I'm not looking for someone to write the code or anything, I am mainly looking for pointers.

```
switch (currentBattleState)
{
    case (BattleState.WAIT):
        {
            if (heroesToManage.Count > 0)
                currentBattleState = BattleState.ACTION_SELECT;
            break;
        }

    case (BattleState.ACTION_SELECT):
        {
            foreach(Button button in buttons)
                button.interactable = true;    
            break;
        }
}
```

This is the current  status of the battle state machine. I have two buttons at the moment, one that will attack and one that will open a spellbook to choose which spell to cast.

What I would need is something like this pseudocode:

```
void OnClicked()
{
    ChooseSpell(); // If it's the "magic" button
    ChooseTarget();

    // And this Action will pass the target to the Attack() or Cast() 
    // function on the HeroStateMachine 
    listOfActions.Add(new Action(origin, target, Attack() or Cast())
}
```

and then when each Action is processed by the BattleStateMachine, like so, again in pseudocode because I have no idea how to do it:

```
void ProcessAction(Function action, int index = 0)
{
    // This would result in Cast(origin, target) or Attack(origin, target)
    action(listOfAction[index].origin, listOfAction[index].target); 
}

// And then call it like this ?
ProcessAction(listOfActions[0].function)
```

we remove it from the list so, basically, this would be a first-in first-out type of thing.

The issue is that I haven't found a way to do that. So far, the videos I've watched are creating a derived class for every single type of attack, spell or item (all derived from a BaseAction)... Which I don't want to do since this seems like really wet code... Also, I wouldn't want to create a whole new class every time I want to add something to the game...

As I said, I'm not looking for full code but so far you've all been helpful so maybe just a pointer to what I could use to do what I want? Or just tell me if I'm approaching this whole thing from the wrong angle.

Comment: Actually it is a good idea to create a new class for each action. Like that you can easily add new actions without modifying existing code. Check out the design patterns strategy and state machine.

Comment: Although I agree with @Greg you may have a look on delegates, ``Action<>`` and ``Func<>`` types and lambdas to add sorts of callback methods to your list.

Comment: @Greg But wouldn't it become super complicated if I have spells with a base damage property, others with a base healing one, others that do something completely different like halve the HP of a target and so on? I agree however that it might be better since I could technically pass the type of weapon used so that, I don't know, maces have a bonus modifier to their damage if the enemy is a skeleton or something

Comment: If each character or object in your game world derives from the same base type or interface, then you can pass these elements to each action. Let's assume everything has HP. The action can then add or subtract HP from the element without having to know what it actually is.

Comment: Yeah, thought about it a bit and it definitely makes sense. It would be easier to add special effects to certain spells, beyond simply Damage() or Heal()... That said, the main issue is that I'm loading all the spells and items from XML and I don't think I could create a new class when "reading" the XML for each one of the spells... I can create instance of existing classes but not entirely new classes... I think

Comment: The XML defines a collection of spells. The class Spell contains a list of magic effects (e.g. List<MagicEffect>). MagicEffect is a base class (or interface) that is implemented by specific effects, e.g. HealingEffect : MagicEffect. Use a factory or builder to create the List<Spell> with matching List<MagicEffect> from your XML.